# JScrollBar not functioning the way i want

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, jscrollbar

so i have a scrollbar, a JTextPane and code to push text to the next line when it hits the edge, however there are several issues. The JScrollBar won't grow any further than a specific size, any text that extends greater than that is no longer visible (because its off screen) and commenting out textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,1500)); causes the code to drop to the next line, to not work. So here is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class WordFrame{

    private JFrame appFrame;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu fileMenu, editMenu, viewMenu;
    JMenuItem saveMenuItem, openMenuItem, newMenuItem, exitMenuItem, fontMenuItem;
    JTextPane textArea = new JTextPane();
    static final int WIDTH = 1280, HEIGHT = 980;
    private JScrollPane scrollBar = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    JPanel wordPanel = new JPanel();
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    private int textHeight = 12;
    private Font defaultFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, 2, textHeight);

    public WordFrame(){
        appFrame = new JFrame();
        setUI();
        addMenuBar();   
        textArea.setFont(defaultFont);


    }
    public JFrame getAppFrame(){
        return appFrame;
    }
    public void setFrameVisibility(boolean isVisible){
        if(isVisible == true){
            appFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
        else{
            appFrame.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
    public void setUI(){
        appFrame.setTitle("Word Processor");
        appFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Bridge.jpg")).getImage());
        appFrame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        appFrame.setLocation(0,0);
        appFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        scrollBar.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        wordPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //1500 allows for scrollbar thing, if i could make this dynamic it would be sweet
        textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,1500));
        appFrame.add(wordPanel);
        appFrame.add(scrollBar);
        wordPanel.add(textArea);
//      appFrame.add(textArea);


        scrollBar.setViewportView(wordPanel);
        textArea.setEditorKit(new WrapEditorKit());

    }

    public void addMenuBar(){
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        fileMenu = new JMenu(" File ");
        editMenu = new JMenu("Edit ");
        viewMenu = new JMenu("View ");

        newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New");
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.setMnemonic('f');

        openMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open");

        fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);

        saveMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
        fileMenu.add(saveMenuItem);

        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);

        fontMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Font");
        editMenu.add(fontMenuItem);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        menuBar.add(viewMenu);      
        appFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }

    public void setFontSize(int i){
        this.textHeight = i;        
    }
    public void addListener(ActionListener listener){
        openMenuItem.addActionListener(listener);
        exitMenuItem.addActionListener(listener);
        saveMenuItem.addActionListener(listener);
        fontMenuItem.addActionListener(listener);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class WrapEditorKit extends StyledEditorKit {
        ViewFactory defaultFactory=new WrapColumnFactory();
        @Override
        public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
            return defaultFactory;
        }

    }

    class WrapColumnFactory implements ViewFactory {
        @Override
        public View create(Element elem) {
            String kind = elem.getName();
            if (kind != null) {
                if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ContentElementName)) {
                    return new WrapLabelView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName)) {
                    return new ParagraphView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.SectionElementName)) {
                    return new BoxView(elem, View.Y_AXIS);
                } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.ComponentElementName)) {
                    return new ComponentView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.IconElementName)) {
                    return new IconView(elem);
                }
            }

            // default to text display
            return new LabelView(elem);
        }
    }

    class WrapLabelView extends LabelView {
        public WrapLabelView(Element elem) {
            super(elem);
        }

        @Override
        public float getMinimumSpan(int axis) {
            switch (axis) {
                case View.X_AXIS:
                    return 0;
                case View.Y_AXIS:
                    return super.getMinimumSpan(axis);
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid axis: " + axis);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

to try explain it in another way just in case my description up above wasn't great. Imagine you are using MicroSoft Word, as you type a sentence the text hits the furthest right of the text area at this point you are automatically dropped to the next line. The last three methods (WrapColumnFactory, WrapLabelView, getMinimumSpan(int axis)) are snippets of code recommended to me to fix a bug that wouldn't do that for me, since there doesn't seem to be any other solution to the problem at this time for the new line bug. The next issue comes with the JScrollBar, at the beginning when you start the application the vertical JScrollBar is there as i wanted however the JScrollBar will only scroll so far, once you occupy the textArea from top to bottom that the JScrollBar permits you to scroll, you can continue typing but the JScrollBar does not increase i.e. you can't see any text beyond that point its like it reaches maximum height. After i decided to comment out textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,1500)) i was hoping that the scrollbar wouldn't be limited in height but what happens instead is the last 3 methods that fix the new line bug don't do anything, thusly text continues to draw off screen with no increased size to the vertical scrollbar and no auto new lines. 
Assistance as always is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Don't set preffered size for the JTextPane.

Instead override method of root View (section view returned by your ViewFactory)

```
public float getPreferredSpan(int axis)
```

to return desired span for X and Y axises

E.g. see how pagination could be implemented

here 
http://java-sl.com/Pagination_In_JEditorPane.html and here http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePrinter.html

Comment: sorry for taking my time in replying, it would seem i have a lot to learn in relation to many aspects of UI design namely in areas like, pagination, editorKits and other things, but thanks for the response, i will try to work on the stuff you mentioned once i get my head around certain things before hand.